# Delayed Jobs on Rails 2: can't save in "perform" method/how to know when job is done?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save, delayed-job

I'm using the Delayed Jobs plugin for Rails 2, and every time I try to modify a model and save it in the "perform" method required by Delayed Jobs, it fails out (no error messages or anything, it's just listed as a failure in the database).

I have the "perform" method in one of my rails model files (Video), and I'm passing an instance of that model (@video, let's say) to the Delayed::Job.enqueue

Is it a known issue that you can't do database modifications while in the queue?  Am I doing something wrong (it only fails when it tries to save, not when I'm actually changing the attributes, and that sounds like a database modification issue).

If this IS expected: How can I fix it?  I'm trying to save a "done" attribute to true, so I know when the model is ready to get to the next step.  Is there some standard way to figure out when a delayed job is done?

EDIT: I have confirmed that calling perform standalone (without delayed job) has no problems with saving (no errors or warnings, or anything).  When I call it through DelayedJobs it fails IMMEDIATELY (no time out) the second it gets to the save line.

EDIT: Wait, I think I see what is going on:  my "perform" is part of an "after_create" call back...  Which is all well and good, until I try to SAVE.  It looks like when I save, it calls perform AGAIN (while already in perform), and that doesn't fly with Delayed Jobs (nor should it).  For some reason I thought after_create would only get called once (not after every save).  Wait, a simple test just showed that that IS the case. Hrrm... So why is perform called twice when I save, and once when I don't, in delayed jobs?

My code:

```
after_create :start_transcodes

 def start_transcodes
     Delayed::Job.enqueue self  
 end
     def perform
      puts "performing"
      self.flash_status = 100
      self.save!
      puts "done"
     end
```

What I see:

```
    performing
    performing
2 jobs processed at 3.3406 j/s, 2 failed ...
```

I don't see it say "done" ever.

What I DO see in my rails log is:

```
"* [JOB] Video failed with NameError: undefined local variable or method `flush_deletes' for #<Paperclip::Attachment:0xb6e51da0> - 2 failed attempts
undefined local variable or method `flush_deletes' for #<Paperclip::Attachment:0xb6e51da0>"
```

I am using the paperclip plugin for this class, and I can call save all day (even in that perform method) and get no problems.  I ALSO can call save(again, even in perform) all day and not see my after_create method called more than once--UNLESS I"m using Delayed Job. (might be it doing some sort of auto retry?)

I'm gonna look around my paperclip plugin, see what's going on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, not sure EXACTLY what was happening, but I've made a skeleton "TranscodeJob" class in my lib directory. This class gets initialized with a reference to what video I want it to process, and processes it, and saves it, and plays nicely with Delayed Job.

Basically, it looks like passing my entire complicated Video object (complete with paperclip plugins) to Delayed Job was freaking things out, and passing a simple object, with no more info than it needs makes things much easier.

Below is the code I used, which works just fine (and if that works fine, i can add my long running code back little by little and confirm it continues to do so, but it worked fine before, just hiccuped with saving)

```
class TranscodeJob
 def initialize(video_id)
     @video_id = video_id           
 end

 #delayed jobs expected method
 def perform
      @video = Video.find(@video_id)
      @video.flash_status = 100
      @video.save!
 end
```

end

This code is STILL called from a after_create filter, and I'm not seeing it called twice, so it looks like I mistoke DelayedJobs auto-retry for recursion, or something.

Answer (score 0):

If your save fails, its got nothing to do with delayed_job ( atleast it shouldn't be unless the save takes longer than the MAX_RUN_TIME. )

Try diagnosing the problem with the save, by not using delayed_job.

Also take a look at the delayed_job.log file in your logs

Comment: But when I run "perform" stand alone (without delayed jobs), nothing goes wrong, nothing fails or errors or anything. If it only has problems under delayed jobs, doesn't that mean it's a delayed job problem? I'll check out the log files, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Er, there IS no delayed_job.log file.  Were you talking about how delayed job writes to the normal rails log file (in this case the development log?)?  If so, like I said, I get no error messages, it just says "2 jobs processed at 0.2683 j/s, 2 failed ...
"  Wait...two jobs? I think I understand, gimme a sec...